# How can I allow users to sign in with 'OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow' via a social identity provider?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a client/server application where I am successfully able to create users with the Microsoft Graph API. I'm also able to authenticate and authorize these users with the 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow' by following these docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc.

But I am also needing to give users the option to login with their Facebook or Google accounts, which doesn't seem to be possible while using this type of grant flow. I'm aware that identity providers can be used with Azure AD B2C, however, I need a way of doing this with my own application and not through a redirect or popup window.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow doesn't support for social identity provider.

In Azure AD, the Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants. ROPC is not supported in hybrid identity federation scenarios. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)(the **Important** tip).

In Azure AD B2C, ROPC supports local accounts only. Users can’t sign in with federated identity providers like Microsoft, Google+, Twitter, AD-FS, or Facebook. Please refer to [ROPC flow notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications#ropc-flow-notes).

Comment: Okay, thats what I was afraid of. Are you aware of any method to use social identity providers in Azure without using B2C?

Comment: @JakeLong Only find the google account method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/google-federation.